# React App Component Not rendering on GitHub Pages. Works locally

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

None of my react components render when I use github pages. My CSS seems to work (I can see the background pattern) but none of my react components render. Everything works fine locally, but it does not when I use github pages. Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/GibbsV3/MySite
I have tried using the Router component but so far I cannot figure it out. Is there something wrong with my index.html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github pages works for static pages.
But react is not static page. Your index.html file interacts with javascript and adds contents, components.
There are some ways you can deploy react-app to github pages but I would recommend using vercel or netlify

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a static page before deploying it to the GitHub page. Follow this [LogRocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/) article.